# Developing a cross-platform self-contained HTML application

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am thinking of building an application, kind of like [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com) in the sense that everything is self-contained in an HTML file, or at least in a bundle where a user won't have to install anything. It works on just about any browser, and on mobile phones (Android and iPhone), and in some browsers (e.g. Firefox), manages to save to the local filesystem without a plugin (albeit, it launches many security warnings, but there are other solutions for that). Other browsers happen to use a Java plugin to bypass this restriction.

Are there any technologies that exist that make this possible? HTML5's [web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage) sounds like it would be almost perfect, except that the data would be tied to the browser.

Any assistance would be appreciated (even if that just means editting / retagging the question to get more folks looking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats about the fileapi: http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi

Comment: This seems to be the closest match, but given its lack of support and other complications, it looks like I'll end up just making a web app after all (though I may experiment with this). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding a relevant comment with this but not exactly an answer...

When you are saying that you want to develop application which contains everything... Then I would like to add about [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com), [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com), and others (Corona)...
This  softwares provides JavaScript base which will be running on all the mobiles (if mobile applications), desktops (if desktop applications) and so on.... But Titanium (as i am working on it) works on the SDK of all the other languages for development...

Now TiddlyWiki, what i have understood from the link is that it is creating a web application or something like that which will work on all the other mobile devices. But this is NOT Good always, Since some application needs to be a NATIVE environment (which is supported by Titanium). Native applications will be much more faster than any other developed applications..